# How to insert Xml element at a specific location using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is my XML,

```
<A>
    <B  id="ABC">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />
      <C name="C" />
      <C name="G" />
    </B>
</A>
```

I need to insert another tag after the last `<C>` tag and output should like ,

```
<A>
    <B  id="ABC">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />
      <C name="C" />
      <C name="G" />
      <D name ="New Tag" >
        <E />
      </D>
    </B>
</A>
```

Using following C#,

`doc.XPathSelectElement("A/B/C[last()]")`.?// Unable to proceed on what operation to make here

I'm trying with c# LINQ Insert/Add methods :(

Any Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `doc.XPathSelectElement("A/B/C[last()]").AddAfterSelf(new XElement("D", new XAttribute("name","New Tag"),new XElement("E")));`

Answer (score 0):

> You are going in right direction with doc.XPathSelectElement
>   Further try using XElement.AddAfterSelf, it will help you to add the specified content immediately after a node. 
>   See the link for more details.

[Original Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.addafterself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)